# Download image from url vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have link in column A. I want to download images from the links in column A.

Below is the code that works for me, but the donwloaded file is not in JPG format. Can we do something to change that? Also, can we change the folder in which the file in being downloaded?

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" Alias _
"URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, ByVal _
szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub getJPGfromweb()
    Dim strJPGLink As String
    Dim strJPGFile As String
    Dim Result As Boolean
    strJPGLink = ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Value
    strJPGFile = ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Value
    Result = DownloadFile(strJPGLink, strJPGFile)
    MsgBox Result
End Sub

Function DownloadFile(URL As String, LocalFilename As String) As Boolean
    Dim lngRetVal As Long
    lngRetVal = URLDownloadToFile(0, URL, LocalFilename, 0, 0)
    If lngRetVal = 0 Then DownloadFile = True
End Function
```

Comment: 1) Is the format of the original image JPEG? 2) What's the value of `strJPGFile`?

Comment: What happens if you open the link from the column A within web browser? Is the image shown in the browser window? Could you please share the link you have the issue with?